# Decide a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem follows as (I have solved a and b, only c left):

$P_3$ is the space of polynomials of degree at most 3.

*a)* Name a base in $P_3$.

*b)* Prove that all polynomials $p$ in $P_3$ that satifies $p(0)=0$ is a subspace $W$ of $P_3$.

*c)* Decide a base in the subspace $W$.

**What I've tried**:

I have solved a) and b), but on c) I have no clue how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the space of polynomials of degree $3$ is not a vector space. For example, $f(x)=x^3+1$ and $g(x)=-x^3+x$ are both polynomial of degree $3$, but $f(x)+g(x)=x+1$ is a polynomial of degree $1$.

So I think you want to say $P_3$ is the space of polynomials of degree at most $3$. And $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$ is a basis for $P_3$.

Now $W=span\{x, x^2, x^3\}$ and $\{x, x^2, x^3\}$ is linearly independent. Therefore, $\{x, x^2, x^3\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Comment: Thanks Paul. But how do you think when you set up the span{${x, x^2, x^3}$}? Because to me I cannot find a good way to think when I am supposed to find a base in this case.

Comment: I see. I think we agree that it is natural to choose $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ as basis for $P_3$. With this basis of $P_3$, when I need to find a basis for $W$, I look at each element in this basis and see which one of this satisfies the condition $p(0)=0$. And I see that $x$, $x^2$, and $x^3$ satisfy the condition because $0=0^2=0^3$. To prove that they really form a basis, I just need to check they span $W$ (which is indeed the case), and they are linearly independent (which follows from the fact that $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is a basis).